# Python3 list.count() time complexity

Tags: python, python-3.x, time-complexity

I've been having a lot of trouble finding documentation on this.  What is the time complexity of list.count() in Python 3?  I've been assuming it's just O(n), does anyone know if this is the case?

Comment: Use [the source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/listobject.c#L2181), Luke! Yes, it's O(n) because it does a simple linear scan.

Comment: https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/c6880edaf6f3/Objects/listobject.c line 2321 so yes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try a bit of an experiment using the `timeit` module.

Timing `list.count(0)` over a large range of list lengths (`10**0` to `10**6`).

```
from timeit import timeit
from math import log10
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = []
for i in [10**x for x in range(6)]:
    data.append((i, timeit.timeit('x.count(0)', setup='x=list(range(%d))' % i, number=1000)))
```

Taking the log of both time and list length for better visualisation (note we are using `log10` here, to match the range of list lengths).

```
log_data = [log10(x), log10(y) for (x,y) in data]
```

Generate a quick plot.

```
plt.figure()
plt.scatter(*zip(*log_times))
plt.xlabel('log(n)')
plt.ylabel('log(time)')
plt.savefig('count_complexity')
```

[image]

It seems that it is indeed O(n) complexity.